# azure devops access log

Tags: azure, azure-devops, audit

I am looking to find access logs for azure devops to

1) List time and date of authorized users who have accessed the code repository
2) List the changes made for all of the the repository and by whom
3) Assuage audit fears of unauthorized users downloading the code

Looks like there is auditing capabilities slotted in the [roadmap](https://dev.azure.com/mseng/Azure%20DevOps%20Roadmap/_workitems/edit/1364977) but I need something now. I tried using the azure portals activity logs but I get zero results for azure devops events

Note: we do not use Active Directory integration yet

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC for version control? In either case, what you're talking about is called "the commit history".

Answer (score 0):

For auditing repo changes, every write operation in source control is part of its history.

For limiting read access, you already know the solution, because you said you aren't using it yet: Azure AD. Limit access to within your organization.

For auditing access, as you said, there is no solution yet, it's on the backlog. The reason it's on the backlog is because there is no way to do it at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. I have initiated the use of Azure AD.