# Is it possible for Azure DevOps to get history of "clone", "fork" and "download as ZIP" by each user?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I would like to get all of the history of Azure Repos.

I would like to get histories of "who/when clone/fork/download repository".

I mean logging of user action.

Is it possible for Azure DevOps(Repos)?

Comment: Have you tried doing the same using Azure AD?

Comment: No. Is it possible with Azure AD??

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, I believe this feature doesn't exist yet. For auditing access or changes etc, a feature as such doesn't exist but by using Azure Active Directory, you can limit the usage or access to say "Read-Only" within your organisation. Also, a similar solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618657/azure-devops-access-log).